# convert from datetime to short date format using javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I want to converts from long date time like this "28/10/2013 12:00:00 AM"
to short date format like this "28/10/2013" using java script but i don't know how..

i tried the following function but it didn't work fine

```
function dateToShort(myDate) {

              var convertedStartDate = new Date(myDate);
              var month = convertedStartDate.getMonth();
              var day = convertedStartDate.getDay();
              var year = convertedStartDate.getFullYear();
              var shortStartDate = day+ "/" + month+ "/" + year;
              return shortStartDate;
          }
```

when i called it with this parameter ""28/10/2013" it return " 5/4/2015 "!!!

Regards

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: All you need, you will find [here at MDN on `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: http://momentjs.com, you're welcome

Comment: Show us that you did some research, what you have tried already. Dont expect to come and just get answers without a little bit of work on your end.

Comment: i added the function that i have but it didn't work fine and return wrong value

Comment: Are you wanting to take the date as text and switch it to the short format or from a generated date?

Comment: i want to take it as text and convert it to short date format

Comment: If you are doing what I think you want and the input string is properly formatted (e.g. 09/09/09) then all you'd need is this `function dateToShort(myDate) {return myDate.substr(0,10)}
document.write(dateToShort("28/10/2013 12:00:00 AM"))`

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem using following simple function

```
function dateToShort(myDate) {

              return myDate.substr(0, 10);
          }
```

Thank you "Rhyono"..

Regards